# How to implement the plotting of a function involving an integral of two parameters in scipy/python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I was trying to calculate and plot a function of an integral with its integrand being a function of two parameters and its upper limit being also a function of one parameter.

Namely, plotting `Integrate(F(x,y)dy)` with lower limit a and upper limit `f(x)`.

When I was running my program with `python main4.py` I was getting the following error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main4.py", line 46, in <module>
    value[idx],errorlow = quad(Zmomentlow1, a, alpha(p), args = (p)) + quad(Zmomentlow2, alpha(p), b, args = (p))
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am using Python 2.7.8.

After consultation with a friend of mine on some other website, I was able to edit the line 46 of the code. This correction made it possible for the code to run without any error message as above. However, this time, the resultant plot is empty meaning all the y-values are zero and I am not getting the expected plot which is attached to the post below (obtained via Mathematica.) [image: snapshot1.png]

```
       """
main7.py
Demonstrates using the arg parameter to 
pass parameters to the integrand function 
when using the quad() function.
"""

# import the needed modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import quad

# define the integrand function 
def F(p, x):
  return 4445.935*np.power(143.753 + 19 * np.log(p/x), -1, dtype=np.int16) * np.power(x, 0.2354424, dtype=np.int16) * np.power(1-np.power(x, 0.375, dtype=np.int16), 5.55373, dtype=np.int16)
def Zmomentlow1(p, x):
  return 2*np.power(x, 2)*F(p, x)
def Zmomentlow2(p, x):
  return 2*np.power(x, 1.7)*F(p, x)
def Zmomenthigh(p, x):
  return 2*np.power(x, 2)*F(p, x)

def Zmoment(p):
  for p, ep in enumerate(p): #make Zmoment(enegrgy) values
    if ep>0 and ep<=c:
      Zmoment[p] = Zmomentlow1 + Zmomentlow2
    elif ep>c:
      Zmoment[p] = Zmomenthigh

# set the parameters
c = 5.0E6 # the energy corresponding to the knee of the cosmic ray flux
a = 0   # lower limit of first integration of low-energy domain
b = 1   # upper limit of second integration of low-energy domain
N = 1000 # number of alpha values to use in integrations

def alpha(p):
        return p/c

p_ary = np.linspace(1.0E2,1.0E11,N) # create an array of values of energy
value = zeros(N)            # create an array to store results of integrations

# do the integrations low1, low2 and high
idx = 0
for p in p_ary:
    value[idx],errorlow = map(sum, zip(quad(Zmomentlow1, a, alpha(p), args = (p,)), quad(Zmomentlow2, alpha(p), b, args = (p,))))
   # value[idx], errorlow = quad(Zmomentlow1, a, alpha(p), args = (p)) + quad(Zmomentlow2, alpha(p), b, args = (p))
    value[idx], errorhigh = quad(Zmomenthigh, a, b, args = (p,))
    idx = idx + 0.001

# plot the result
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(p_ary,value)
plt.ylim([-0.01,0.01])


# note the new syntax for the xlabel() and title() commands
# that allows the use of LaTeX commands
xlabel('energy [GeV]') 
ylabel('Zmoment')
title('Plot of Z-moment vs. Energy') 
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Figure1')
```

Comment: You are passing a function (`alpha`) to `quad` where you have to pass a float. Maybe this should be `alpha(energy)` but that of course depends on your problem.

Comment: Hi yes Christoph, that is actual issue here. I asked some of my friends who have worked with python. But, they had not encountered such special case where one of the limits are not a float. I hope I could know of some way around this.

Comment: with alpha changed to alpha(energy) I am actually getting a different error message which is under the original message above.

Comment: It seems all the error boils down to the this line                value[idx],errorlow = quad(Zmomentlow1, a, alpha(p), args = p) + quad(Zmomentlow2, alpha(p), b, args = p)                                                   When removed, it is compiled without error but doesn't give me the plot:(